# In iOS, how can I get the address of self as a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime

If it matters I need this particularly when self is a UIView subclass. By way of example to clarify my question, the following stmt:

```
NSLog(@"self: %@", self);
```

gives the following output:

```
<RCLDataView: 0x10971a0b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>
```

I want just that address (0x10971a0b0) without the rest of the text. I suppose I can (somehow) capture that full string and (somehow) extract the address with NSString methods. But that seems really ugly. There is probably a way to get the address directly, since NSLog can get it.

Comment: See the docs for format specifiers. You want `%p`.

Comment: `%@` says use the `description` method of the argument (if it has none, it will use the default `NSObject` implementation) As @rmaddy said, you want to use a different format specifier, specifically `%p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", yourString];

unsigned long long address = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:addressString];

[scanner scanHexLongLong:&address];
NSLog(@"%llx", address); //Prints the address
```

The first line gets the pointer address and puts it into an `NSString`.
The next line instantiates an unsigned long long to hold the hex value of the pointer. The pointer address representation is `64 bits` *I think* so we need a `64 bit` value to hold it. I know an `int` is not large enough but a `long long` works. Alternatively you could use a `uint64_t` depending on your architecture. The next two lines are to extract the hex value and store it in our `long long`. The `NSScanner` method is the only way I know to get a hex value from an NSString so I just used that. The last line of course is to print the value to make sure it's correct. You can check if it's correct by also printing the `addressString`.

Comment: What is hexInt? It looks like something was left out here. Don't I just want addressString as the result?

Comment: @RobertL That was a mistake I made when I was testing out the above code. And as for addressString, it depends on what you want to use the address for. If you're using it in any kind of C function and it requires an address parameter or something then you need a primitive value of the address as you can't pass in Objective-C objects like NSString.

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. Add a description too.

Comment: `unsigned long long` will work, of course, but there is actually a type -- `uintptr_t` -- that is defined to be big enough to hold an address, whatever the size is on the current architecture. There's also apparently a [`printf()`/`scanf()` format macro for this size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228414/603977).